# Register Activity with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I'm trying to create a Register Activity for my app. I'm using this code:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String nome = params[0];
        String email = params[1];
        String pwd = params[2];
        String data="";
        int tmp;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://6senseofficial.it/api/login/register.php?");
            String urlParams = "nome=" + nome + "&email=" + email + "&pwd=" + pwd;

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            while ((tmp = is.read()) != -1) {
                data += (char) tmp;
            }
            is.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return data;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception 1: "+e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception 2: "+e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Whenever i control the new camps on my DB, all the params are empty.
Some know why? Thanks.

The code for PHP file register is this:

```
<?php include('../../mysql.php'); ?>
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$nome = $_GET['nome'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$pwd = $_GET['pwd'];

$data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "INSERT INTO utenti (nome, email, pwd, datacreazione) VALUES ('$nome','$email','$pwd','$data')";
if(!mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo '{"message":"Unable to save the data to the database."}';
}

?>
```

Comment: No we don't, because you're not showing us. Check the code that calls `doInBackground()` And you really should be using url encoding.

Comment: Nothing, i find the error.

Comment: As @Xorifelse told, you should consider to be using UrlEncoding. Also there is security vunerability if password is part of GET request. GETs are cached in proxies, logged in many devices on the road etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending GET requests, you should append query string to URL, not to body.

Proper code should be:

```
String urlParams = "nome=" + nome + "&email=" + email + "&pwd=" + pwd;
URL url = new URL("http://6senseofficial.it/api/login/register.php?" + urlParams);
```

And remove lines with OutputStream.